# GIT commit cannot commit after antivir scann and restart

Tags: eclipse, git, bitbucket

Everything worked fine unit today.

Symantec/Antivir scanned and restarted my computer and afterwards my workspace looked like this.

Does anyone know what I can do?
How can I set the HEAD once a again?
In local the paths are all removed.

[image: Problem]

[image]
[image]

Comment: I had to checkout the project again and afterwards I copied the .git folder into the original project - afterwards everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can always clone the project again to get the latest code from the repository.

Another option is to execute `fsck` and recover from dangling files.

```
# Search for all uncommitted added files = dangling content
git fsck --full

# print out the content of the dangling content
git show <SHA-1>
```

If the content is commited simply use `git reflog`

More info in more detailed can be found here:
[How to move HEAD back to a previous location? (Detached head)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-checkout-revert-reflog-reset-old-commit/34519716#34519716)

---

**A single line command, breached into multiple lines only for readability**

```
# You can try recovering a branch by resting your branch to the sha
# of the commit found using a command like: 
git fsck --full --no-reflogs --unreachable --lost-found | 
    grep commit | cut -d\  -f3 | xargs -n 1 
    git log -n 1 --pretty=oneline > .git/lost-found.txt

# Display the above commits 
git log -p <commit>

# OR: 
git cat-file -p <commit>
```